# Appending to CommaSeperatedIntegerfield in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I created a model which has CommaSeparatedIntegerField

**models.py**

```
class ForumPosts(models.Model):

    ....
    path = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(blank=True,max_length=50)
    ...
```

I want to use this model and defined my view as below
**views.py**

```
def create_forum_post(request, ..):

    ...
    forumpost.path.append(forumpost_id)
    ...
```

I encountered a situation where I had to append forumpost_id which is an integer into path which was defined as CommaSeperatedIntegerField. While debugging i got an error

'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'.

I think it might be due to lack of comma i tried lot of variations of the same code but unable to add forumpost_id to path. Thanks in advance

Comment: You meant string concatenation?

Comment: I tried string concatenation also but its not working i think it might be exclusive to CommaSeperatedIntegerField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CommaSeparatedIntegerField`'s value will not be deserialized automatically, the only feature of this field type is the validation (it must be comma seperated integers).

You need to retrieve the field value, deserialize it, append new integer, serialize and save it back.

**EDIT 1:**

Example:

```
class ForumPosts(models.Model):
    # ...

    def append_to_path(self, value):
        path_list = self.path.split(',')
        path_list.append(value)
        self.path = ','.join(path_list)
```

Usage:

```
forumpost.append_to_path(forumpost_id)
forumpost.save() # save will validate if the path is correct
```

Comment: I am very new to django so if you don't mind can you explain how to deserialize. I just know its related to json/xml but not sure how to implement in the context of CommaSeperatedIntegerField.